# MS Sql - Escape special characters in large text

Tags: sql, sql-server

inserting large HTML into an SQL table, I need to escape all quotes and other special characters. 
I know that in C# I can simply do this:

```
myString = @"<p> this is my paragraph </p>";
```

can I do this in MS SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean you're trying to run a text query, like in SSMS? I *think* the only thing that needs to be escaped is the `'` so you should be able to select the text block, and do a find-replace to replace `'` with `''`.

*Note: If you are running this from code though, you should be using a parameterized query, pure and simple.*